# SQL Joins stop working when table columns are defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, odbc, inner-join

I am using sql to create a custom ODBC query into Excel.

I have 2 tables 'TBL_CONTACT' and 'TBL_ADDRESS' that I want to INNER JOIN on 'contactid', which is a column that exists in both.

This works fine if I select all columns, but stops working if I start defining the columns I want to show.

Working code:

```
SELECT * FROM "TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT

INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "TBL_ADDRESS" AS ADDRESS) ADDRESS
ON CONTACT.contactid = ADDRESS.contactid
```

Non-working code:

```
SELECT CONTACT.contactid, CONTACT.fullname FROM "TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT

INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "TBL_ADDRESS" AS ADDRESS) ADDRESS
ON CONTACT.contactid = ADDRESS.contactid
```

This only shows the 'contactid' and 'fullname' columns from 'TBL_CONTACT' and doesn't join anything from 'TBL_ADDRESS'.

EXAMPLE:

```
TBL_CONTACT
contactid   firstname   fullname
1001        John        John Smith
1002        Tom         Tom Adams

TBL_ADDRESS
contactid   line1       line2        postcode
1001        3 Farm Ln   Essex        AB1 1BA
1002        1 Tim st    Kent         CN2 2NC
```

Desired result:

```
contactid   fullname     contactid2  line1       line2    postcode
1001        John Smith   1001        3 Farm Ln   Essex    AB1 1BA
1002        Tom Adams    1002        1 Tim st    Kent     CN2 2NC
```

1st code gives following result:

```
contactid   firstname    fullname     contactid2  line1       line2    postcode
1001        John         John Smith   1001        3 Farm Ln   Essex    AB1 1BA
1002        Tom          Tom Adams    1002        1 Tim st    Kent     CN2 2NC
```

2nd code gives following result:

```
contactid   fullname
1001        John Smith
1002        Tom Adams
```

I'm fairly new to SQL but am not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your description doesn't do a good job conveying the problem, especially because both queries work.

Comment: And write table names before fieldnames in `SELECT` statement: `SELECT TBL_CONTACT.contactid, TBL_CONTACT.fullname,  TBL_ADDRESS.contactid, TBL_ADDRESS.fullname`

Comment: specify alias name in column

Comment: The 1st query should not run at all, what is `"DATABASE"`? Of course you won't get columns from the 2nd table when you don't list them in SELECT

Comment: When you have two (or more) columns with the same name you have to qualify them, e.g. `TBL_CONTACT.contactid`.

Comment: Sorry for my first description - I have added much more detail and corrected my code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining a table results in the columns being available for your select. When you select all columns (with `*` like in your first code snippet) the columns of your joined table will be selected, too. However, when manually selecting columns, you have to define which columns you want from your joined table, too.

Let's say you want to have the 2 columns *contactid* and *fullname* from your Table TBL_CONTACT and all columns from the joined table TBL_ADDRESS:

```
SELECT `TBL_CONTACT`.`contactid`, `TBL_CONTACT`.`fullname`, `TBL_ADDRESS`.* FROM TBL_CONTACT 
INNER JOIN TBL_ADDRESS
ON `TBL_CONTACT`.`contactid` = `TBL_ADDRESS`.`contactid`
```

Backticks are optional.

Alternatively, you could specify columns for the joined table, too.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not appreciate the joined table had to be included in the original select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//MySQL
SELECT TC.contactid,TC.fullname,TA.`address_table_column` 
FROM TBL_CONTACT TC
INNER JOIN TBL_ADDRESS TA
ON TC.contactid = TA.contactid

//SQL Server
SELECT TC.contactid,TC.fullname,TA.[address_table_column] 
FROM TBL_CONTACT TC
INNER JOIN TBL_ADDRESS TA
ON TC.contactid = TA.contactid
```

Comment: address? @Thomas did not mention this field at all

Comment: Square brackets for delimited identifiers are MS SQL Server specific. MySQL has back-ticks. (And ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g `"address"`.)

Answer (score 0):

Wnen  you have joined multiple tables and you select some field you must specify
to which table the field belongs .

Because like in your case the same field can be in both tables and then mysql does not know which one to fetch.

So just use the table prefix in your query and of course `SELECT` all the fields you want:

```
    SELECT `TBL_CONTACT`.`contactid`,`TBL_CONTACT`.`fullname`,`TBL_ADDRESS`.`contactid` as contactid2,`TBL_ADDRESS`.`line1`,`TBL_ADDRESS`.`line2`,`TBL_ADDRESS`.`postcode`  FROM `TBL_CONTACT`        
    INNER JOIN `TBL_ADDRESS`
    ON `TBL_CONTACT`.`contactid` = `TBL_ADDRESS`.`contactid`
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not giving me the joined columns - I have added some more detail to my original question if this helps.

Comment: "This only shows the 'contactid' and 'fullname' columns from 'TBL_CONTACT' and doesn't join anything from 'TBL_ADDRESS'." .....Actucally It DOES join but of course it shows what you SELECT....Just  `SELECT` all the field you want.I updated my answer...

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT contact.*, ADDRESS.* FROM "TBL_CONTACT" contact INNER JOIN "TBL_ADDRESS"  ADDRESS  ON contact.contactid = ADDRESS.contactid;
```

Comment: While this may solve OP’s problem, it would be better to provide some context on what you actually fixed.